# SQL SELECT... IN result order

Tags: mysql

Here is the scenario - I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stylemaps` (
`zyid` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
`styid` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'zzzz0000Z',
UNIQUE KEY `zyid` (`zyid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

A typical set of entries in this table might be

```
zyid        styid
qrst1234    abcd1230
abcd9876    abcd1231
pqzx4569    abcd1232
bcde0000    abcd1233
```

i.e. the order of entries for zyid is fairly random.

Now suppose I issue

```
SELECT styid FROM `styles` WHERE zyid in ['abcd9876','bcde0000']
```

the result I get is

```
abcd1231
abcd1233
```

i.e. the rows are ordered in the same way as the ***IN*** clause my SQL statement.

My question is this - can I rely on this always being the case (so long as I order the IN clause entries correctly)?

If this ever fails and I end up mapping styles incorrectly the end results are liable to be completely garbled.  The alternative would be to do

```
SELECT zyid,styid
```

instead of

```
SELECT styid
```

and then do some more work on the results to guarantee the right mapping.

Comment: I think, but am not sure so no answer, that the behaviour is undefined. There is no need for any implementation to order your results if you don't ask for it. So while the implementation of the server _might_ give you consistent results, you can and should _not_ rely on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with:

```
  SELECT styid
    FROM `styles` 
   WHERE zyid IN ['abcd9876','bcde0000']
ORDER BY FIELD(zyid, 'abcd9876','bcde0000')
```

Comment: Thank you.  That appears to work - I suspect that quite apart from being a more reliable way of doing things it will also be faster since the PHP sort(array) function is liable to be quite sow.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot depend on the results being in order of the `IN` contents. Here's why:

- Each row is checked in an order based on the most efficient order that the query optimizer chooses. If you have no other condition in your `WHERE` clause and you are viewing all columns (or have no indexes other than `PRIMARY`), this means the optimizer chooses to do a table scan, so it reads all rows in the most efficient way. In your result, this happens to be the order of your first output.
- For *each row*, it performs a [binary search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) of the entries in the `IN` clause. This makes the search (for each row) quite efficient, but doesn't alter the order of the rows.

In short, the order of the rows you get when you use an `IN` clause is no different to the order you get without using the `IN` clause, but you can affect that order by changing the statement in other ways, such as by using `ORDER BY`, giving you the most control; or (if you have other indexes) by using other elements in your statement that changes the way the optimizer reads rows.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, Jeremy.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot rely because in the end the DBMS Optimizer decides what to display first.

Answer (score -2):

Simply add an 'order by' clause at the end, eg

```
SELECT styid FROM `styles` 
WHERE zyid in ['abcd9876','bcde0000']
ORDER BY styid
```

Comment: -1 Won't work. The OP loses their desired order with this statement.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: It wasn't clear to me from the question that the OP wanted to maintain that order. What if one time the query was written 'where zyid in ['abc', 'def']' and one time 'where zyid in ['def', 'abc']'? How is the 'in' clause built? Maybe there should be a separate field which defines the display order.

Comment: "the rows are ordered in the same way as the IN clause" - that gives me a clue that that's the order the OP wanted. You can define the display order in the same way the accepted answer has provided.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: I got the impression that the OP was *complaining* that the order of the results depended on the order of the IN clause