# Using SELECT...IN (), how can I order the results to match the order in IN (...) list?

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, where-in

Essentially, I have same question like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20656196/607407), but or Oracle database.

Consider select:

```
SELECT
USERS.USER AS USER,
USERS.ID AS ID
FROM
USERS
WHERE USERS.ID IN (1,3,2)
```

I want the results to be ordered by their occurrence in the `IN (1,3,2)`. This should be the output:

```
USER | ID
-----+----
 Foo | 1
 Bar | 3
 Baz | 2
```

Note the order is 1,**3**,2, not 1,2,3.

What's the nicest way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
              their sort order
                       v     v     v
order by decode(id, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3)
                    ^     ^     ^
              elements in IN list
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it. Is there a variant of this function that doesn't require explicit numbers for the order? Eg. `decode_simple(id, 1,3,2)`?

Comment: You're welcome. ORDER BY can't know which values you used in the IN list, nor how they are ordered unless you tell it so. Therefore, no - I don't think that there's a simpler option.

Comment: What I meant is that in the linked question, the function used for mysql infered the order from the argument order. So maybe if there's a similar simplification for oracle, I'd use that...

Comment: If there's any, I don't know about it.

Comment: "Is there a variant of this function that doesn't require explicit numbers for the order?" -> see below `xmltable` + `ordinality`.

Answer (score 1):

Order is not applicable to elements in list.

However you can use xmltable or collection to specify the order.

```
with users(id, usr) as
(
select 1, 'Foo' from dual
union all select 2, 'Bar' from dual
union all select 3, 'Baz' from dual
)
select *
from users
join xmltable('1,3,2' columns id for ordinality, o int path'.' ) using (id)
order by o;

with users(id, usr) as
(
select 1, 'Foo' from dual
union all select 2, 'Bar' from dual
union all select 3, 'Baz' from dual
)
select *
from users
join (select rownum id, value(t) o from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,3,2)) t) using (id)
order by o;
```

`Collection iterator` returns elements in the same order as they specified in constructor.

So you rely on the behavior of collection iterator.

Please note that demonstrated approach works fine if source rows are continuously numbered from 1 to n.